# SDK 4.7 appears to break ActiveTrack on Phanton 4 Pro

Tags: dji-sdk

Following the update to SDK 4.7 I see a failure in the ActiveTrack on the Phantom 4 Professional.

> 2018/08/23 19:10:58>TrackMode.setRecommendedConfiguration failed: The feature is unsupported.

The code worked with 4.6.

I am using all defaults; aka, not setting tracking mode or gesture.

I've sent email to DJI regarding this issue and will report back.

Reporting here for information to others in case they see the same issue and/or identify a work-around.

Comment: It looks a bit more involved.   I find that the call appears to work but it returns not supported.   4.6 did the same but due to code changes I didn't see the error,  more I don't continue if an error was reported

Comment: it will be fixed in next version.

Comment: Hopefully the new version will be soon since it breaks active track???  Is the a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and DJI will have a fix issued in the next release